# Why can't i execute this code in C++ with vectors implemented in class and functions?

Tags: c++, vector

So i have a school project and i'm trying to execute this code which solves a quadratic equation using as many c++ objects and learned things. the problem is i want to save the a,b and c in a vector and then use them but i can't just pull this off. can someone tell me how can i fix my code?
Ps. the cout-s and variable's names are in my native language so hope it doesn't bother you.
Thanks in advance!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<vector>
using namespace std

;class ekuacioni{
private:
int v [3];

public: void rrenjet(vector<double> &v)
    {double x1,x2,rrenjadall,a,b,c;
    a=v[0];
    b=v[1];
    c=v[2];

        rrenjadall = sqrt(dallor(v));
        x1= (-b + rrenjadall )/(2*a);
        x2 = (- b-rrenjadall )/(2*a);
        cout<<"Ekuacioni ka dy rrenje te ndryshme te cilat jane";
        cout<<"x1= "<<x1<<endl;
        cout<<"x2 ="<<x2<<endl;
    }
   public :void rrenja(vector<double> &v)
    {
        double x,a,b,c;
            a=v[0];
    b=v[1];
    c=v[2];
        x = -b/(2*a);
        cout<<"Rrenjet jane te barabarta, x1=x2= "<<x<<endl;
    }


   public: double dallor( const vector<double>& v)

{
double x,a,b,c;
a=v[0];
    b=v[1];
    c=v[2];
return (b * b) - (4 *a *c);

}
}
;


 int main() {
class ekuacioni e;

double koef [3];

cout<<"Vendosni koeficientet a,b dhe c te ekuacionit:\n";
for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
cin>>koef[i];
double dallor= e.dallor(koef);
if(dallor<0)    
 {cout<<"ekuacioni nuk ka rrenje reale si zgjidhje te tij."<<endl;

 }
else
 if (dallor==0)
 {e.rrenja(koef);
 }
 else
 {e.rrenjet(koef);
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: _"i can't just pull this off"_ is not an acceptable problem statement.

Comment: C++ is not C# or Java, you don't need to `public:` before every method or member.  I suggest making sections and placing all public methods into one section that is associated with `public:`.

Comment: Why do you have the `;` from `using namespace std` on the same line with `class ekuacioni`?

Comment: @NathanOliver haven't noticed i may have done it while trying to fix the code, thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::vector<double> koef;
double k1, k2, k3;
cin >> k1 >> k2 >> k3;
koef.push_back(k1);
koef.push_back(k2);
koef.push_back(k3);
```

There are other possibilities for loading a vector from an input source.
There is no need for the array `koef`.  I have made it into a `std::vector` so it can be passed to your other functions.

Comment: Wow !! Thank you very much :)  this worked and all the errors are gone but my functions doesn't seem to work and when i run the code the values  that x1 and x2 get are nan :/ do you know why?

Comment: I highly recommend using a debugger.  Let this example be a good opportunity to increase you skill with a debugger.  Print out or display values of variables as you execute each statement separately.  Also review that the variables are initialized correctly.